# Improve Navigation Bar

Tags: html, asp.net, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a question. If you see the picture. The first line menu(Frans) is little bit rare when you compare the second line menu (My Trips,Search Trip, New trip,etc). The color is black and position some how looks inappropriate.

Currently I'm using navbar-collapse to make the menu and using label to show the name of the account (Frans). Here is the code:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                        <li ..(My Trips)..</li>
                        <li>..(Search Trip)..</li>
                        <li>..(New Trip)</li>
                        <li><asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="Label</asp:Label></li>


</ul></div>
```

Anybody knows how to change this?Thanks

[image]

Comment: You didn't show a lot of code and what exactly do you want to do about it?

Comment: @Sharar, the only thing I would like to know is only that part. I want  to know if I can change the label into something else